# Prove that if $|a_1\sin x+a_2\sin2x+a_3\sin3x+\cdots+a_n\sin nx|\leq|\sin x|$ for $x\in R,$then $|a_1+2a_2+3a_3+....+na_n|\leq1$

Tags: inequality, derivatives

Prove that if $|a_1\sin x+a_2\sin2x+a_3\sin3x+\cdots+a_n\sin nx|\leq|\sin x|$ for $x\in R,$then $|a_1+2a_2+3a_3+\cdots+na_n|\leq1$

When we try to differentiate it on both sides wrt $x$,then modulus sign comes,how will one prove this question?Please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Divide both sides of the inequality by $|{x}|$ and let $x$ tend to zero. Compute the limit for each term in the sum using $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(bx)}{x} = b$$